# Setting envs or globals in bash script [NOT A duplicate]

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I'm looking for a way (preferably cross-platform compatible) to set something globally accessible from a bash script.

My company is using a bash script to request access credentials to a mysql database. This returns username, password and db domain that I end up having to copy paste in my terminal to run and connect to our mysql db.

I thought i'd amend the script to set environment variables and make use of these in an alias with the credentials set in my bashrc but turns out you can't set environment variables in a bash script.

So i tried to set the mysql alias with the username password and domain pre-filled in that same script but same issue. Can't set an alias in a bash script.

I essentially want to be able to run the script that gives me the credentials and then not have to do manual copy pasting all over the place.

What I tried was (if it give more context):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Script gets the credentials
# Script now has username, password, endpoint variables
export MYSQL_USER=$username
export MYSQL_PASSWORD=$password
export MYSQL_ENDPOINT=$endpoint
# Script finishes
```

and in my bashrc:

```sh
alias mysqlenv="mysql -h $MYSQL_ENDPOINT -u $MYSQL_USER -p'$MYSQL_PASSWORD'"
```

I appreciate this is not working and that might not be the best solution so i'm open to other options.

PS: Forgot to mention the credentials expire every 24H which is why i want to smoothen the process

PS2: I can't source the script that gives me the credentials because it's not just exporting environment variables, it's taking params from the cli and getting me to log in to my company system on my browser, etc.

PS3: I know putting password for mysql on the command line is bad practice but this is a non-issue as that password is being printed there in the first place by the script that give me the credential (written by someone else in the company)

Comment: Show the output of the script that spits out the credentials.

Comment: Environment variables are only inherited by child processes. There's no way to set variables in a parent process.

Comment: Why don't you put your MySQL defaults in `~/.my.cnf`?

Comment: @Barmar, I'm aware, this is just an example to give an idea of what i'm trying to achieve. As I said, i'm looking for other options. There is probably a standard way to achieve what i'm trying to achieve but i'm just not aware of it

Comment: @glennjackman how would that help? The output is text based and contains the credentials

Comment: There's no way to do it without sourcing the script or putting the commands in a shell startup script like `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Barmar because they are not defaults, those credentials expire after 24 hours, after which I have to rerun the script to get new credentials

Comment: @Barmar can a function in `.bashrc` set environment variables?

Comment: Yes, because the .bashrc is *sourced* not *executed*

Comment: I'm asking for the output of the script because you need to be able to capture and parse the output in order to get the values into variables.

Comment: But that would be at startup, i don't wanna have to restart my laptop to get the new credentials, essentially I wanna be able to run the script that gets me the credentials or a layer above it and that would "preconfigure" either an alias or mysql itself or something else so that I don't have to copy paste credentials around

Comment: @glennjackman I'm able to parse the output to isolate the credentials using `awk`

Comment: You can't change environment variables in another process. Only the process itself can change its variables.

Comment: @Barmar, i'm looking for another solutions, open to suggestions

Comment: Are you saying that you're only allowed to run this script once per day? I don't understand why you're talking about startup.

Comment: @glennjackman The credentials are set to expire after 24 hours, so every day for every database I use I need to run the script and copy paste credentials around to be able to log into the dbs. No I can run the script as many times as I want

Answer (score 2):

Since you can already parse the credentials, I'd use your awk code *to output shell commands*:

```sh
getMysqlCredentials() {
    credential_script.sh | awk '
        {parse the output}
        END {
            printf "local MYSQL_USER=\"%s\"\n", username
            printf "local MYSQL_PASSWORD=\"%s\"\n", password
            printf "local MYSQL_ENDPOINT=\"%s\"\n", endpoint
        }
    '
}
```

then, I'd have a wrapper function around mysql where you invoke that function and *source the output*

```sh
mysql() {
    source <(getMysqlCredentials)
    command mysql -h "$MYSQL_ENDPOINT" -u "$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD" "$@"
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing something like this but wasn't sure if this was the cleanest way, also thought that maybe there was a unix standard to do it

Comment: This way you don't have the credentials hanging around in the environment. I know you said security isn't a concern, but still.

Comment: Also this way, you don't have to remember to pre-execute the credential script: it gets called only when you want them.

Comment: Oh, you've edited it, that looks good enough to me will mark as answered thanks

Comment: Actually this is almost it. The script that gets me the credentials shouldn't run every time I wanna run mysql as it has a big overhead. They would need to be cached in some way

Comment: So, cache the credentials in a file. When you need to check the cache, ensure (1) the file exists and (2) the file was written today (use `stat`). If not, call the credential script and cache the values.